# How to Resolve that the command is too long issues while using the maven-jdeps-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

In my project having more dependency. So I want to analyze classes for how many classes depend on JDK unsupported.

Plugin Configuration in POM.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jdeps-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jdkinternals</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <recursive>true</recursive>
                <multiRelease>11</multiRelease>
                <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but while building the project faced issues like **the command line is too long**

Currently I am using:
**Java Version:**

```
openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 11.0.17+8-adhoc..jdk11u)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM OpenLogic-OpenJDK (build 11.0.17+8-adhoc..jdk11u, mixed mode)
```

**maven version**

```
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (******)
Maven home: E:\Setup\apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 11.0.17, vendor: OpenLogic, runtime: C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-11.0.17.8-hotspot
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

how to resolve the command too is long issue, while using the maven-jdeps-plugin